# Zip.js read contents of file inside zip

Tags: javascript, unzip, zip.js

Im working with zip.js, and able to get and proces the zip file, but im stuggling to read the file inside the zip. Im able to create the blob to download (e.g blob:null/e830b738-1014-40db-a0d3-642acf2dc498), but cant find a way to read the conents into a variable?

thanks in advance

Attempted to use new FileReader() but was unable to get any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution

```
 $.ajax({
    url:href,
    success:function(html)
    {
        console.log(html);
    }           
})
```

In the demo you just need to add this to the success of the download file event (you will need to change trigger as this only works on click but should help with solution)
[image]